# Repository + UnitOfWork + EF Updating Master Record when detail records changed. (TotalAmount = Sum(Amount))

Tags: entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

i'm trying to implement a Repository and UnitOfWork patterns using Entity Framework.

This is the scenario:

An user can add or modify detail records in a master-detail window and when hit "save" the added/modified records are sent to the server.

Then i perform a CreateOrUpdateMultiple().
CreateMultiple add the new records to the repository.
UpdateMultiple retrieve records that going to be updated.

After the two operations completes i need to update the master record with a sum(field) with all detail records. (With all i mean the existing ones that were not modified and the ones in memory)

This is what i have thought so far...

1. Being purist with repository pattern i should retrieve all detail records and then should mix in one list the existing records (modified or not) and the addded ones, and then do the sum operation, but what if the amount field of detail records is a database calculated field?
2. Read from database only records to be updated (thinking this will be faster because if i have 40 records and just 3 are modified and 2 added i will not read the entire set) and then **somehow** perform the update to the master record, but the problem is those records aren't yet in the database.

I have just one ObjectContext instance for all operations and i call SaveChanges() in my service to commit all in just one transaction.

What do you advice me to do? Or how do you archieve this kind of situation?

Thanks in advance

//Update

Here more technically described

The is what i have right now using transactionScope... and this is what i'm trying to avoid because of all the calls to database

```
//Service Layer
Method()
{
   Method1.Invoke(masterRecordId, detaildRecords); //
}

//Business Layer
Method1(masterRecordId, detailRecords)
{
     using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
     {
          var recordsToUpdate = dal.RetrieveOnlyRecordsToUpdate();

          //Update retrieved records with the values of recods comming from the client
          dal.Update(recordsToUpdate); //ctx.ApplyChanges(); and ctx.SaveChanges();

          dal.Add(recordsToAdd) //ctx.Add(detail records); and ctx.SaveChanges();

          //Update master record TotalSum
          dal.UpdateMasterRecord(masterRecordId); //Here is performed ctx.ExecuteStoredCommand("UPDATE MasterTable = SUM() WHERE MasterRecordId = {0}")...

          Method2();

          ts.Complete();
     }
}

Method2(masterRecordId)
{
     using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
     {
          MasterRecord m = Retrieve(masteRecordId);
          Notification notification = new Notification(){ ...assign properties..., m.TotalSum};

          dal.Add(notification); //ctx.Add(notification); and ctx.SaveChanges();

          ts.Complete(); 
     }
}
```

This is what i want to do...

```
//Service Layer
Method()
{
  Method1.Invoke(masterRecordId, detail records);

  UnitOfWorkManager.Current.Commit(); //
}

//Business Layer
Metodo1(masterRecordId, detail records)
{
          MasterRecord masterRecord = repository.Retrieve(masterRecordId);

          var recordsToUpdate = repository.RetrieveOnlyRecordsToUpdate();

          //Update retrieved records with the values of recods comming from the client
          repository.Modify(recordsToUpdate); 

          repository.Add(recordsToAdd); 

          //Here i'm stuck and i'm thinking it should be something like this.
          masterRecord.TotalSum = sum(detailRecords in memory + detail records in database); //
          repository.Modify(masterRecord); //

          or

          //Another way somehow...

          //Then keep going with the udpated master record
          Method2(masterRecord);
     }
}

Method2(masterRecord)
{
     //Create notification
     var notification = new Notification(){ ...properties.., masterRecord.TotalSum};
     repository.Add(notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it as transaction and call `SaveChanges` only once you must do it in your application before `SaveChanges` is called. So generally you must get sum before you do any change and modify the sum by updated values, inserted values and deleted values. Then you will set the new sum value into the master record. If you do it this way you will have unit of work.

Why other approaches are not so good.

- Calculated field in database. This will require manually reloading master entity after the save operation because saving detail cannot reload changes in other entity. Moreover database logic will probably require trigger on detail table to modify sum in master table.
- Updating master record after saving changes to details breaks unit of work.

Comment: Thanks, ok, i understand it... now without the calculated fields and updating master record after saving changes i just have to solve how to get the sum... i added some code to focus more the problem...